# How to fade two images together in Sketch

Tags: mask, sketch-app

[image: get rid of seem?]

Is it possible in Sketch3 to do a mask w/ a gradient to make these two images seemless? Basically this technique (for photoshop) http://www.wikihow.com/Fade-One-Image-Onto-Another-in-Photoshop

...how do I do this in Sketch 3?

Comment: Online masking tutorial in sketch:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DgI_0em9kc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible.

1. Insert a rectangle around the first image.
2. Select both rectangle and image, and mask it: Layer / Mask with Selected Shape.
3. Select the Mask and switch it to Alpha Mask: Layer / Mask Mode / Alpha Mask.
4. Fill it with a Linear gradient, set the start color to transparent and the
   end color to black.
5. Adjust the angle of the gradient from top/bottom to left/right.
6. Do the exact same for the second image, but set the angle of the gradient right/left.
7. Move the second image slightly on top of the first image.

And voila:

[image]

Download the sketch file: http://ge.tt/7j2J7J12/v/0?c